# How to get the lowest representable floating point value in C++

Tags: c++, standard-library

I have a program where I need to set a variable to the lowest representable (non infinite) double-precision floating point number in C++. How am I able to set a variable to the lowest double-precision floating point value?

I tried using std::numeric_limits. I am not using C++11 so I am unable to try to use the lowest() function. I tried to use max(), but when I tried it, it returned infinity. I also tried subtracting a value from max() in the hope that I would then get a representable number.

```
double max_value = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
cout << "Test 1: " << max_value << endl;    
max_value = max_value - 1;
cout << "Test 2: " << max_value << endl;
double low_value = - std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
cout << "Test 3: " << low_value << endl;
cout << "Test 4: " << low_value + 1 << endl;
```

Output:

```
Test 1: inf
Test 2: inf
Test 3: -inf
Test 4: -inf
```

How can I set low_value in the example above to the lowest representable double?

Comment: 18.3.2.4 of the (C++11) standard says that max() is finite. So I guess the double or the ostream implementation is buggy. Or you can try to fiddle with compiler options like "exact float computations" equivalent.

Comment: @PeterSchneider OP: "... I am not using C++11 ..." ...........

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would `cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` print? The gcc wiki has some information about issues arising from 80 bit precision hardware vs. memory layout of doubles but I'm not sure it really applies here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: @Theolodis it's the one I have here; I cannot imagine that `max()`s definition has changed between standards. It's not `max_plus_epsilon()` after all ;-)

Comment: 'cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max()' printed infinity also. There must be something wrong with my iostream.

Comment: You could assign it to long double and print then! -- Ah, just read your answer. Nice. -- or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have -inf (you got it), you can get the lowest finite value with the [nextafter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nextafter/) function on (-inf,0).

EDIT: Depending on the context, this may be better than `-DBL_MAX` in case `DBL_MAX` is represented in decimal (thus in an inexact way). However the C standard requires that floating constants be evaluated in the default rounding mode (i.e. to nearest). In the particular case of GCC, `DBL_MAX` is a long double value cast to double; however the long double value seems to have enough digits so that, once converted from decimal to long double, the value is exactly representable in as double, so that the cast is exact and the active rounding mode doesn't affect it. As you can see, this is rather tricky, and one may want to check on various platforms that it is correct under any context. In a similar way, I have serious doubts on the correctness of the definition `DBL_EPSILON` by GCC on PowerPC (where the [long double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) type is implemented as a [double-double arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic)) since there are many long double values extremely close to a power of two.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library [`<cfloat>`/`<float.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) provides macros defining floating point implementation parameters.

The question is somewhat ambiguous - it is not clear whether you mean the *smallest magnitude* representable non-zero value (which would be `DBL_MIN`) or the *lowest* representable value (given by `-DBL_MAX`).  Either way - take your pick as necessary.

Comment: In general (e.g. on IEEE 754 systems), `DBL_MIN` is not the number that has the smallest magnitude, but the smallest positive _normal_ number. The positive number with the smallest magnitude is `DBL_TRUE_MIN` (well, in C11, I'm not sure about C++), which is different from `DBL_MIN` when you have _subnormals_.

Comment: @vinc17 : It seems that in any case -DBL_MAX is what is required in any case.

Comment: Yes, however there may be implementation issues with `DBL_MAX`: under some conditions, it may yield an incorrect value.

Comment: @vinc17 : As you say in your answer, depending on the purpose that may not matter - floating point is not simple to get right in very subtle ways in many cases - up-voted your answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer again because the definition of GCC actually appears to be correct, though it is rather fragile (for instance, I'm not sure that it is correct with any compile flag, and it may easily break in the future).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a bug in the iostream that I was using to print the values. I switched to using cstdio instead of iostream. The values were then printed as expected.

```
double low_value = - std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
cout <<"cout: " << low_value << endl;
printf("printf: %f\n",low_value);
```

Output:

```
cout: inf
printf: 179769...
```

Comment: Oh. Printing the double as int doesn't mean much (what's the inf bit pattern of a double? 179...?)

Comment: Use `%f` to print a double

Comment: Sorry, that was I typo on my part. I had used the %f in my code but wrote %d out of habit here without noticing.